# Codeigniter, Is there a way to get user error reports automatically?

Tags: php, codeigniter

It is frustrating to get error reports from users via email. I bet that most users wouldn't send a bug report to developer. Therefore, I wanna set up that if the user get PHP error codes, I would like to get the error reports automatically via email.

Is there a way to get user error reports in PHP or CodeIgniter?

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of errors we are talking about here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
<?php  
// Our custom error handler  
function email_error_handler($number, $message, $file, $line, $vars)  
{  
    $email = " 
        <p>An error ($number) occurred on line 
        <strong>$line</strong> and in the <strong>file: $file.</strong> 
        <p> $message </p>";  
    $email .= "<pre>" . print_r($vars, 1) . "</pre>";  
    $headers = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";  
    // Email the error to someone...  
    error_log($email, 1, 'you@youremail.com', $headers);  
    // Make sure that you decide how to respond to errors (on the user's side)  
    // Either echo an error message, or kill the entire project. Up to you...  
    // The code below ensures that we only "die" if the error was more than  
    // just a NOTICE.  
    if ( ($number !== E_NOTICE) && ($number < 2048) ) {  
        die("There was an error. Please try again later.");  
    }  
}  
// We should use our custom function to handle errors.  
set_error_handler('email_error_handler'); 
// Trigger an error... (var doesn't exist)  
echo $somevarthatdoesnotexist;
```

[**Source**](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/quick-tip-email-error-logs-to-yourself-with-php/)

Answer (score 0):

PHP logs usually to the apache error log (if you're using apache), which is usually at `/var/log/httpd/error_log.`

CodeIgniter's error log, if enabled in config.php, is set to log by default to your `application/log/date.php` (Where date is today's date).

If you want, you can set a cron that emails you every hour of new changes in either (or both) files. Or you can create your own PHP error handler using `set_error_handler` function in PHP.

Edit: mbinette has pasted a good example that uses PHP's `set_error_handler` function. One caveat, this won't let you know about fatal 500 errors, the error log will.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the codeigniter's documentation about error reporting 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/errors.html

There is a mention about error_reporting() function, probably you can hack it and do your email stuff.

Comment: Actually, `error_reporting` is only for setting the error reporting level. To do the email stuff, you'd have to use `set_error_handler`